# How to send email with attachment of dynamic view file in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, sendmail, email-attachments

> I am working on CI project where i want to send email for particular
>   user with attachment of one pdf. I am trying to send my dynamic view
>   file that is i am generating with m_pdf but its not working for me.
>   it's not attaching anything. show me error of '**ci_loader can not be
>   used as a string**'.

this is my controller function:

```
public function emp_pdf()
    {
      $this->load->model('my_model');
      ob_end_clean();
      $this->load->library('m_pdf'); 
      $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
      $dataObj=array('id'=>$id);
      $data['data_pdf']=$this->my_model->method($dataObj);
      $this->load->view('layouts/emp_pdf',$data); 
      $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('abc@gmail.com');
      $this->email->to();
      $this->email->subject();
      $this->email->message();
      $this->email->attach($this->load->view('layouts/emp_pdf',$data));
    }
```

As you can see above i am getting data with id in one array from my model 
`$dataObj=array('id'=>$id);
 $data['data_pdf']=$this->my_model->method($dataObj);`

and passing this array to my view file 
`$this->load->view('layouts/emp_pdf',$data);`.

I am using this same function for view file or for download pdf and its working great but same file if i am attaching for mail its not working.
`$this->email->attach($this->load->view('layouts/emp_pdf',$data));`

I search lot things on net but didn't get solution.
How to load my view file as attachment in codeigniter.thanks in advance.

Comment: did you refer the codeigniter document  ?https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 0):

Comment out first `$this->load->view('layouts/emp_pdf',$data);`

and use the buffer function: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::attach

> If you need to use a buffer string instead of a real - physical - file
>   you can use the first parameter as buffer, the third parameter as file
>   name and the fourth parameter as mime-type

```
  $attach_str = $this->load->view('layouts/emp_pdf',$data,true); // true returns 
  $this->email->attach($attach_str, 'attachement', 'somename.pdf', 'application/pdf');
```

Also your email lacks a `to`, `subject`, and `message` but I assume you haven't added that yet.

Comment: i added `to` etc but not mention here. my mail function is working. now let me do as per your solution i will let u know if getting problem thanks